# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade After flutter clean

Tags: flutter

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\nobit\AndroidStudioProjects\Production\secret_keeper\build\app\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\out
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:80)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:522)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3451)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingParams.getAllDexFiles(DexMergingTask.kt:502)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:423)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\nobit\AndroidStudioProjects\Production\secret_keeper\build\app\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       163.3s (!)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Got this exception after running flutter clean, before clean it's working but after clean it showing this  exception.

> flutter doctor -v
>
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.19041.685], locale en-IN)
> • Flutter version 1.22.5 at C:\FlutterSDK\flutter
> • Framework revision 7891006299 (4 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
> • Engine revision ae90085a84
> • Dart version 2.10.4
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.2)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\nobit\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
> • VS Code at C:\Users\nobit\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.16.0
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
> • vivo Y21L (mobile) • c98e68ea • android-arm • Android 5.1.1 (API 22)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with multidex builder.

Go to android/app/build.gradle and add the following lines of codes:

```
dependencies {
  implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```